# Custom Taxonomy Link Text Echo Name Not Slug

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, loop, variables

I'm a little lost about where I can place a simple php echo within a loop.

I have a "program" taxonomy where each program is echoed onto buttons. Right now I'm only echoing the slugs for the link text. However, one of the taxonomies has two words, so naturally when I echo the slug, the hyphen appears.

Is there a way to easily remove the hyphen or create a variable like `$program_title = get_the_program_name`?

Code:

```
    $program_slug = get_the_program_slug($post);
    $program_names = get_terms('program', array('orderby' => 'names', 'fields' => 'all', 'hide_empty' => false)); 
    if ( $program_names && ! is_wp_error( $program_names ) ) {
        $program_slugs = array();
            foreach ( $program_names as $program_name ) {
                $program_slugs[] = $program_name->slug;
            }
    }

    <?php foreach ($program_slugs as $program_slug) { ?>
        <div class="button <?php echo $program_slug; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() . '/' . $program_slug; ?>">
              <?php echo $program_slug; ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Replacing the link text (the last  `$program_slug` variable) with something like `$program_title` doesn't work.

Comment: `get_the_program_slug()` isn't a WordPress function, I would say, you have to show it, to get the help you want.

Comment: do you mean provide a screenshot?

Comment: No, show the code.

Comment: My apologies; it's a custom function seen [here on line 67](https://github.com/ksascomm/ksas_flagship_academic_grll_f5/blob/master/functions.php)